# In Django, is a column's default value used if a row is added with raw SQL?

Tags: database, django, postgresql

I noticed that, for the most part, Django does not enforce default values on the database level.

Field definition in model:

```
description = models.TextField(default='')
```

SQL:

```
description | text   | not null
```

If I add a row using raw SQL (as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), and don't include a value for a field that has a default, will the default still be used?

Comment: Note that in your case, since your default value is blank, you can merely write `models.TextField(blank=True)` which lets Django know that blank values are acceptable, in which case it will save the field with a blank value when saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

At least, not based on a test I just did.

models.py:

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
    mailing = models.ForeignKey(Mailing, related_name="recipients")
    email = models.EmailField()
    how_sent = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SENT_TYPES, default="U")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_viewed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s -> %s (%s)" % (self.mailing, self.email, self.date_sent)
```

And then I rand this code:

```
>>> cursor.execute("""insert into mailings_recipient (mailing_id, email) values (3, 'test@example.org');""")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "path/to/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/django-pyodbc/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'how_sent', table 'database.dbo.mailings_recipient'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

If Django entered default values for you, it would have sent a value of "U" for `how_sent` but instead I got an error.

Then if we create a record using Django,

```
Recipient.objects.create(mailing=Mailing.objects.all()[0], email='test@example.org')
```

this is the corresponding SQL:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON INSERT INTO [mailings_recipient] ([mailing_id], [email], [how_sent], [user_id], [date_sent], [date_viewed]) VALUES (1, test@example.org, U, None, 2012-09-14 14:48:59, None) 
;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

So if you are really asking whether default values will be entered for you if you use something like `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO...")` then the answer is *no*, it will not set up those default values for you. As you pointed out, Django does not set up the default values for you when creating your database schema, it merely sets up those default values when performing a normal save.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old (17 years old as of 2023) [known issue in django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470). Default value are not enforced on the db layer but rather implemented in django. Looks like a [solid PR](https://github.com/django/django/pull/16092/files) is almost ready to be merged so for future readers it might be doable using `db_default` field.

If not, another way currently is to add an SQL `ALTER` statement inside the migrations.

```py
from django.db import migrations
    from django.db.migrations.operations import RunSQL

    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
        dependencies = [
            ("app_name", "0001_initial"),
        ]
        operations = [
            RunSQL(
                "ALTER TABLE orders ALTER COLUMN price SET DEFAULT (0)"
            ),
        ]
```